# matplotlib grid randomly skips middle value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

I am working on plot customization. I have a plot constructed from a dataframe called `res`, the index being a datetime index, and have tried to add a grid.

```
labels = res.index
mWh = res['mWh']
mWh_predicted = res['mWh Predicted']

x = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.35

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,15))
ax.grid(True)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: str(int(round(x)))))

rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, mWh, width, label='mWh')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, mWh_predicted, width, label='mWh Predicted')

ax.set_ylabel('mWh')
ax.set_title('mWh Generated vs. Regression Predicted mWh')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

For some reason, adding the grid randomly skips out on the middle value.

[image]

I am also wondering how to customize yticks when the data comes from a dataframe. I have tried setting as a range but have had no luck. I would ideally like the ticks to increase/decrease by 100000, with minor ticks (unlabeled) at intervals of 50000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the yticks question.

```
step = 100000
minor_start = 50000
yticks_major = np.arange(0, 11 * step, step)
yticks_minor = np.arange(minor_start, 10 * step + minor_start, step)
ax.set_yticks(yticks_major, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(yticks_minor, minor=True)
```

Comment: when I do this, they all cluster at the bottom and the lines go far beyond them

Comment: I may have misread the scale - thought it was zero to 10 million. If it is zero to 100 million then you should change the value of step to 10 million and minor_start to 5 million.